# How to express: I wish...

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

大家好！

I had a question that I have often asked my native-Chinese speaking friends, but I have not been satisfied with the answer.  In English, I find myself often saying, "I wish..."  For example:

I wish I could go to the movies tonight, but I have too much work to do.

I wish that I would have thought of that earlier.

I wish I had bought this book at the beginning of the semester.

I wish I did not have to go to work every day.

My friends have often given me the translation 希望, but I feel like this is hope.  But I feel like this may not be appropriate for things that cannot come true.  In all the examples above, "I hope" is not accurate.  And if I said, say, "我希望每天不要上班” I feel like I am saying, "I hope I do not have to go to work every day."

How can I express this "wishful" thinking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options that clearly state that it cannot come true:

- I wish I could go to the movies tonight, but I have too much work to do.

我 **本想**（本来想要）今晚去看电影，但要做的事情太多了。

我 **倒想**（倒是想要）今晚去看电影，但要做的事情太多了。

- I wish that I would have thought of that earlier.

我 **真希望** 我之前能想到，（现在说什么都晚了。）

- I wish I had bought this book at the beginning of the semester.

我 **真希望** 我一开学就买了这本书，（但当时钱不够啊。）

我 **本想** 我一开学就买了这本书，（但后来忘记了。）

- I wish I did not have to go to work every day.

我 **真希望** 不用天天上班。

我 **倒想** 不用天天上班。

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  When you wrote: 我 真希望 不用天天上班。  How do you know if this means: I really hope I do not have to work every day, vs. I really wish I did not have to work every day.  Is it just based on context?

Comment: "真", "倒" or "本" means it cannot come true. It might be called subjunctive mood (not sure the terminology). For example, "I really hope I do not have to work every day" can be used in the context: "我希望我不用每天上班，所以我辞掉了上一份工作找了份兼职，一周只需要上两天班。", vs "I really wish I did not have to work every day."  - "我真希望我不用每天工作，但没有办法，我需要赚钱养家。"

Answer (score 3):

As a native Chinese speaker, I think “我本想”，“我本以为”，“我本打算” are the answers to your questions.
For example, your first sentence:
I wish I could go to the movies tonight, but I have too much work to do.
Translations could be:
我 本以为 我 今晚 能 去看电影，但 我 还有 非常多 的工作 要做。

Pay attention that it should be "本来以为", but we usually say “本以为” for short.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  Is it correct to say that the 我本想...  approach could be translated as, "I wanted to go to the movies, but I had too much work."  Or 本打算, I was planning on going to the movies, but I had too much work."  

Is it correct that this is slightly different than wishful thinking?

Comment: You are right! However, don't worry about these differences. They are trivial and have the almost same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I know what you mean, but for me, 希望 or 想 are natural and accurate words in Chinese when you explain "I wish". What confuses you in Chinese is the intonation we use you should pay more attention. **What's different between Chinese and english is Chinese verbs don't have tense**. Because of the intonation, one word in Chinese can have several different meanings.

When you use positive intonation like 我**希望**明天是个好天气！(which means I hope it will be a sunny day tomorrow!) It explains the same meaning as I hope...

When you use negative intontion like 我**希望**每天不要上班. Other people can understand what you think about is unrealistic. If you want to stress your intonation, you can add 真 or 太 in your sentence.(我真希望每天不要上班or我太希望每天不要上班就好了）

My suggestion is you could pay more attention to the intonation when your friends speak. And ask him whether a word has other meanings when using up or down intonation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  If you will pardon my ignorance--what do you mean by positive/negative intonation?

Comment: @The_Anomaly In this case, I think it just means up/down voice. When you speak in a negative way, maybe you are in a bad mood. In contrary, positive intonation is always used to make a real wish in the future. I hope that's clear.

Answer (score 1):

for something in the past or present, it can be translated to "要是……就好了"
examples: 
I wish that I would have thought of that earlier.
我要是早点想到这个就好了。
I wish I did not have to go to work every day.
我要是不用每天上班就好了。

it's kind of like "if only..."

for something in the future, you just need to say “我想……”
example：
I wish I could go to the movies tonight, but I have too much work to do
我想今晚去看电影，但是还有好多事情没做呢